# Black triangle drawn on grid background instead of grid's contents in WinRT

Tags: xaml, background, grid, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

So I have a grid with a background.  Inside the grid is a WebView and then some space on the left hand side of the screen where I have just placed a Button for now.

As the program runs, the left hand bar (that shows the grid with the background and the button laid out on it) doesn't render, instead I get the background, no controls on it and a black triangle (or geometric shape) at the bottom.

I suspect it's an issue with the VM and the video driver.  I had a similiar issue with WPF a few years ago and MS's response was that I had an incompatible video driver that was causing the form to not render correctly at all times (this is very much the same behavior).

What can I do to prevent this?  I'm including an image.

I'm going to include the small XAML I used and then a screenshot of the behavior (The XAML I rekeyed by hand):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Media/Background.jpg" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Margin="15,15,0,0">Sample Label</TextBlock>
    <WebView x:Name="wv1" Margin="250,0,0,0"></WebView>
    <Button Content="Do Something" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" Margin="57,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Click="Button_Click1" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: 1024x1024.  I should note, when the program loads, it generally renders fine.  Also, I've moved the project to a VM on updated hardware and so far this behavior doesn't occur (I saved the test project in the my DropBox so it's using the same solution files).

Comment: Are you using the same machine you had problems with WPF on a couple years ago? Maybe it's still a problem with your driver?

Comment: Would it still happen if you used an Image control instead of the ImageBrush?

Comment: Good question, yes, it's the same machine that I had the WPF rendering issue on.  I don't have the stats on the video card but I can get them.  On that machine it happens every time the apps is run, but I haven't found a trigger (I have a WebView and it usually seems to happen after it has Navigated or the screen changed in some capacity).  I will try the Image instead of ImageBrush and get back to you.

Comment: I tested, it happens with an Image also (I got rid of the background and put an Image control on the form.  If I click the button on the form, then mouse out of the "image" area it fails to totally redraw estimated every other time.  The same project works though on my home machine (which is new hardware).  When I mouse back into the Image or Mouse over the Button, the Image (or ImageBrush) redraws itself (sometimes fully, sometimes not).

Comment: Have you tried getting a new driver?

Comment: Yes, I have the most updated drivers available for my video card on the host machine.  Here's the catch though, the "box" having the problem on is a Virtual Box VM.  That's one reason I suspected it maybe a video driver that I can't do much about (but wanted to make sure).

Comment: Well, why not say that first? :) VMs don't usually work well with multimedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMs don't work well with multimedia. You should expect all sorts of problems with video.

Comment: I did, but I only said "I suspect it's an issue with the VM and the video driver."... I didn't go into detail about VM particulars so it got lost easy in the mass of text I posted. :D  Thanks again Filip.  You seem to address all of my WinRT questions as I'm learning it.  ;)

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed that. I am glad I can help, although there are still vast areas of WinRT that I have not explored yet. I'm just learning with everyone here.